# Convert sqlite date column to timestamp column

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table A where I have two columns: D and T. D column contains dates in a format of 2013-07-10 05:01:01.000000. T column is empty for not, but its time is BINGINT.

What I want to do is to populate T column rows with timestamps converted from D column. Is there an SQL magic that can help me? Or I need to query D column rows first, save then into some list and then update T column rows?

[image: Database snapshot]

On this image you can see column D on the left, ID column on the right and column T in the middle.

Column D is VARCHAR, column T is BIGINT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update A set T = strftime('%s', D)
```

should do the work, but it's just from the documentation and never used

Comment: nice one. But the result is missing 3 digits, meaning that an output is in seconds, while a timestamp should be in milliseconds. How can I change your code to get a milliseconds precision? Apart of multiplying it by 1000 (which is kinda hack as it sacrifices precision)

Comment: The docs mention an example with juliantimestamp (D) as the same as strftime (..), but with fractions of seconds

Comment: another shot would be strftime('%s%f', D)

Answer (score 0):

For [strftime](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), `%s` returns only whole seconds, while `%f` returns seconds including the fractional part, but in the range 0–59.
It would be possible to extract the fractional part from the latter, but those digits are identical with those in the original string, so it would be easier to just extract them with a string function:

```
UPDATE A SET T = strftime('%s', D) || substr(D, 20)
```

(This also works correctly when the original date has more than three digits.)

Comment: `UPDATE A SET T = strftime('%s', D) || substr(D, 20)`

this produces the same result as 

    `update A set T = strftime('%s', D)`, so still 3 digits are missing

Comment: Works for me. Is the format of `D` really what you wrote in the question?

Comment: CL, yes. The format is exactly the same as provided in the question.